# count with where clause

Tags: php, sql

I've tried putting a where clause in several different places and can't figure this out. I've read questions that have already been asked but no fix so far.  I want the `COUNT` for `items.item_aprv='1'` but no matter where I put it I get an error. I've included the entire .php file for reference.

```
<?php

include 'header1.php';
?>
<div id="templatemo_main">

<div id="content_full" class="float_r">
<br><h10>Browse Mints</h10><br><br>
<?php

$search="SELECT mint.*, COUNT(items.item_id) as total
    FROM mint
    LEFT JOIN items ON mint.mint_id=items.item_mint
    GROUP BY mint_id
    ORDER BY `mint_name` ASC ;";

$items=mysql_query($search); 
while($it=mysql_fetch_array($items)) {
?>          
<div class="mint_box">

<h10 style="font-size:15px;">
    <a href="mintitem.php?id=<?php echo $it['mint_id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $it['mint_name']; ?>
    </a> (<?php echo $it['total']; ?>)
</h10>
</div>          
<?php
} 
?>
<div class="cleaner h10"></div>
</div> 

<?php
include 'footer.php';

?>
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM items WHERE item_aprv='1';

Comment: Note that this MySQL extension is depreciated; you should move to using either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: It's helpful to show the actual error you get. The error messages contain important information.

Comment: And yes, you should switch to prepared queries using mysqli or PDO in order to prevent injection attacks. The exception is if you're using PHP entirely for static queries and NEVER putting user input into a query.

Comment: I know it's outdated, I'm modifying a script that is already done. I will have to probably outsource an update to PDO of the whole site when I have everything working as it should.  Right now I'm just trying to get it all doing what it's supposed to do.  Thanks for the tips guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT mint.*, COUNT(items.item_id) AS total 
FROM mint 
LEFT JOIN items ON mint.mint_id = items.item_mint 
WHERE items.item_aprv = '1'
GROUP BY mint.mint_id 
ORDER BY mint.mint_name ASC
```

As a side note, you should use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for your queries. It is much safer and the old way is deprecated.

Comment: Not really. Here is what the page should look like, http://www.silverartcollector.com/browse.php and here is what happened when I used the above code http://www.silverartcollector.com/browse2.php

Comment: Try with `mint.*` (edited above). It looks like it is filtering and getting the counts correctly, which is the main point....

Comment: This works! Actually, it culls out the zero count mints as well so I like it even better.  Thank you very much!